# bootstrap-sass gem doesn't install bootstrap files (.css or .scss)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use `bootstrap-sass` and am having trouble. I created a new app with Rails 3.2.16 and added these two lines to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
```

(`bootstrap-sass` instructions here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

I ran `bundle install` and thought the  gem would somehow install the relevant Bootstrap files, but that's not the case. For example, no CSS (or SCSS) or JS files were installed:

```
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/borrar$ find . -name \*css\*
./app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/borrar$ find . -type f -name "*.js"
./app/assets/javascripts/application.js
```

Am I missing some step in the installation process? I could just copy the files by hand from Github, but that seems to be missing the point: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets

Update: Is it possible that Rails gets the stylesheets directly from the Gem package here?

```
1.9.3-p448 :001 > Sass.load_paths
 => ["/home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS/js files are in the gem and are pulled in to your application at run time as needed. If you'd like to inspect them run `bundle open bootstrap-sass`.

Comment: That is correct, thanks! My problem started with an existing application where there was an old `bootstrap.css` file installed under `vendor/assets/stylesheets`. It was conflicting with the new `bootstrap-sass` installation. I just needed to delete that old file and now it's working.